# C - Executing bash command with 2 pipes

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, exec

I have an assignment for which I have to create C programm which has to do the following: The mother proccess has to send via pipe to the child proccess the result of the command `ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c`. The child proccess has to take this result and write it to a file `users.log`.

This is the code I have written:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int file_number;
    pid_t pid, pid_2, pid_3, pid_4;
    int n, pd[2],fd[2], zd[2];
    char line[MAXLINE];

if ( pipe(pd) < 0 || pipe(fd) < 0 || pipe(zd) < 0)
{
    perror("cannot create pipe.");  // failure on create pipe
    exit(1);
}

if ( (pid = fork()) < 0)
{
    perror("cannot fork");   // failure on creating child proccess
    exit(1);
}
else if ( pid > 0)  // mother proccess
{
    dup2(zd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(zd[0]);
    close(zd[1]);
    if ( (pid_4 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot fork.");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid_4 > 0)
    {
        dup2(pd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pd[0]);
        close(pd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execl("/bin/ps", "ps",  "hax", "-o", "user", (char *)0);
    }

    if ( (pid_2 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot fork.");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid_2 == 0)
    {
        dup2(pd[0], 0);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(pd[0]);
                close(pd[1]);
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);
        execl("/bin/sort", "sort", "", (char *)0);
    }

    if ( (pid_3 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot fork.");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid_3 == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(pd[0]);
                close(pd[1]);
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);
        execl("/bin/uniq", "uniq", "-c", (char *)0);
    }

    close(pd[0]);
            close(pd[1]);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);

    pid_t terminated;

    int stat;

    while ((terminated = wait(&stat)) > 0)
    {
        printf("Child %d terminated.\n", terminated);
    }

}
else           // child proccess
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen("users.log", "a+");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open file.\n");
    file_number = fileno(fptr); // getting the file descriptor of fptr
    dup2(zd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(zd[1]);
    close(zd[0]);
    n = read(zd[0], line, MAXLINE);
    printf("Output: (%.*s)\n", n, line);
    write(file_number, line, n);
}

return 0;
}
```

Running the code seems not to produce the desired result. Nothing is written to the file and I get this error:

```
Signal 17 (CHLD) caught by hax (procps-ng version 3.3.10).
hax:display.c:66: please report this bug
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You say you have to pipe "the result of the bash command", but you are not running `bash` at all.  Instead, you appear to be attempting to simulate its behavior in your own program.  It's thus unclear to me whether the question does a poor job of conveying your actual requirements or whether you're making this a lot harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I mean I have to execute the command  `ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c` inside my C programm and write its result to a file.

Comment: But as for the error you reported, it is the complaint of a program that reports itself as "`hax`", which is not among those you're supposed to be running.  It would thus be worth your while to check your `execl()` calls.  Remember that the second argument to `execl()` becomes the *first* (`argv[0]`) of the program that is executed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes ok, I corrected this but still can't get what I want.

Comment: You would be wise to check the return values of your function calls, which for the most part you do not do, and to handle failures when they arise.  In particular, if `execl()` fails then it is essential that you terminate the process in which it was called.

Comment: Additionally, the first child (running in the final `else` block) must take care of all its inherited file descriptors.  chances are good that the `sort` command is never terminating because the first child still has both ends of pipes `pd` and `fd` open.

Comment: Note also that its weird that you make such a special case of the first child.  It's not particularly more distinguished from the other three children than they are from each other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I kind of solved the problem and accomplished what I wanted by replacing `execl` with `execvp`  and rearranged a bit the job of the mother process. Also added checks for the returned values of function calls.

Comment: If the problem is solved, I suggest deleting the question. There’s no answer and it probably doesn’t have long-term benefit to other people.